# How to intercept and change values

Tags: java

I'm developing in eclipse (java 6) and working with websphere server.

How can I automate a dynamic modification of some small parts of the code (mock-like) for my local development only? I don't want to share my own adjustments with other developers... That could create bad expectations including them thinking it should be working in a certain way that is not correct or even outside communications not happening as they should.
I'm not using any java framework, that is what has been decided for the project.

I have already looked at ASM and BCEL but I can't find any good source on how to get them working in an automated way for this kind of thing... If they are capable of it.

The changes I need can all be achieved by intercepting values of parameters of some specific methods (some are static and other are not static) when they are called.

Anything that can be automated to get that result without changing any of the code shared between the other developers can do. It doesn't need to automatically adapt to new code.

I have already been called to attention of my own adjustments being sent to the repository and I want to avoid it at my best capability.

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite unclear what you are trying to achieve but it sounds like you want local modifications to the code? If so, modify the code, commit the changes to a branch that you never publish. Merge incoming changes into this branch every now and then.

Comment: Use a local repository, then. Git makes this a breeze.

Comment: I wish it was that simple for the dev enviournment I have :). I really do prefer git but the files must be in the same place

Comment: That is not an argument against Git.

Comment: I get what you want to mention but if I do that, I will only make it more difficult or require more steps every time I want to make a commit to the common repo. That is, then, a non-solution to me and I have the tendency of forgetting steps machines can do automatically. Anyway, after lots and lots of research I made a plugin to eclipse. My friends told me it is a very dangerous plugin so I'm reluctant to share it.

Comment: Then I don’t really know what exactly you are looking for: you are unwilling to make local changes, and your changes should not go into the common repository. I don’t see any other way here because those changes have to be somewhere.

Comment: I can have local edits as metadata of the edits that happen locally. I did find a solution that uses that... Actually, that's what my plugin does. Thanks anyway.